# How can I update a count field in one table by actually counting rows in another table?

Tags: sql

I have two table. I need to fill a field in one table by counting the other table.
I wrote this query, but it doesn't work:

```
update  Publisher
set Publisher.[Count]=Count(Document.Id)
From Publisher inner join Document
on Publisher.Name=Document.Organization COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: You should post your tables structure

Comment: And please tell us what database system you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server, you'd like to fix this by putting `group by Publisher.Name` at the end of the query. However, this isn't permitted in an update statement. So you have to use a correlated subselect instead:

```
update  
    p
set 
    p.[Count] = (
        Select Count(*) 
        From Document d 
        Where p.[Name] = d.Organization collate database_default
    )
From
    Publisher p;
```